# View deleted console output

Tags: java, eclipse, console

I am running multiple Junit tests, running a test results in the console being cleared and populated with the log of the current test. Where will the log file containing the previous test logs be stored. Is there any way in eclipse, by which i can see such deleted logs.

Comment: By default the log's won't be stored anywhere, you can use a logging framework like logback or log4j to store the logs to a chosen location.

Comment: Answer by @user714965 good. If you agree accept it.

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK: The solution works fine in cases where we have configured the output file as mentioned. But it still doesn't work for already deleted console output. As G-Man has mentioned there is no default storing enabled for the logs, and thus can't be retrieved.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following:

- Open your Run configuration
- Select the tab `Common`
- In the `Standard Input and Output` group activate `File` and set a file
- Select the `Append` Checkbox
- Run your configuration

That way everything which is printed to the console will also be printed into that file.

Comment: I tried this and it did *not work*.  ...even when selecting "Run" directly from the "Run Configurations" window.  ...even after creating the specified .txt file manually.  (It seems like it should work, but it does not.  Please edit the answer to include what are obviously important missing steps.)

Comment: @A.M. The answer contains everything necessary.

Comment: You are 100% right.  I was choosing the wrong path.  I was derailed after I trying and failing many times to get the "Workspace..." syntax to work (How do you specify the file name after the ${workspace_loc:/myworkspace} that gets generated?  Typing it (file.txt) directly afterward doesn't work.  Typing it after a forward slash or backslash also does not work.) before giving up and using the "File System..." syntax instead, but in any case...my bad!