# In Eclipse, how do you specify a file using the "Workspace..." syntax (e.g. ${workspace_loc:/myworkspace} ) (for a console log)?

Tags: java, eclipse, console, logfile

I was following the instructions in this answer: [View deleted console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929235/view-deleted-console-output)

(to set up a file in which Eclipse will record everything that goes to the console <sub>(too bad that is not done by default!)</sub>), and under:

- Run Configurations

  - Java Application

    - Common (tab)

      - Standard Input and Output

there are 3 options

- Workspace...
- File System...
- Variables...

I wanted to use "Workspace...", and I selected my workspace, which generated text like this in the text box:

> ${workspace_loc:/myworkspacesubfolder}

I wanted to specify the file name, and I tried all of these forms:

> ${workspace_loc:/myworkspacesubfolder}test.txt
>
> ${workspace_loc:/myworkspacesubfolder}/test.txt
>
> ${workspace_loc:/myworkspacesubfolder}\test.txt

...but none of them worked.  (No errors alerts were thrown, but neither was the text file generated upon running the program.)

<sub>(I then gave up and used "File System..." instead of "Workspace...", which takes a standard path such as</sub>

> C:\test.txt

<sup>, but...)</sup>

What *is* the proper syntax for using "Workspace..."?

Answer (score 1):

The proper syntax for this is:
${workspace_loc:/myworkspacesubfolder/test.txt}
Make sure that you manually create test.txt file in that location. I is not created automatically by eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is `${workspace_loc:/myworkspacesubfolder}/test.txt`. This works even when the file does not already exist.

See [this Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=235166) for an explanation of why `${workspace_loc:/myworkspacesubfolder/test.txt}` doesn't work when the file doesn't already exist.

Comment: I want to finally get around to accepting an answer here, but your suggestion is exactly one of the things I tried and wrote above did not work (the 2nd line under "I tried all of these forms:".  Am I missing something?