# Java console showing old and deleted messages

Tags: java, netbeans, pdfbox

I am using netbeans 8.0.2 , JAVA 1.8.0_60 and PDFBOX 1.8.10

When I am trying to run my program, suddenly it has started showing old console messages, which even I have deleted or changed. I did clean and rebuild and then it works for first run and for consecutive runs its doing the same. It is not a feasible solution to clean it everytime I need to see the result of some changes.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929235/view-deleted-console-output) has a same problem but he is working with eclipse and mine is netbeans.. so I dont have same settings.

I have checked it on new java application without pdfbox and running other projects on netbeans,, it is working fine. I have restarted the IDE but with no help. To me, it seems the problem is with the project itself not netbeans. But I don't know how to resolve it.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please remove PDFBox from the question and tags, as the problem wasn't related to it.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow on my netbeans for this project, "compile on save" option is not working. It is at:

Run >> Set Project Configuration >> Compile >> "compile on save".

I unselected that option and tried to do manual build and run, which is working.

Dont know if anyone else has same problem, but could be helpful for someone searching the solution.